# How to update an array outside a function (pointing to pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function which takes as input, a pointer to a 2D array, and a pointer to a 1D array.

```
int resize(double *x, double **y, int n){
```

The aim of this function is to resize both x and y to be twice their length (n).

I create two new arrays- which have been doubled in length

```
double **yTemp = NULL;
double *xTemp = NULL;
xTemp = new double[2*n + 1];
yTemp = new double*[2*n + 1];
```

I then loop through and replace the values of xTemp with and yTemp with x and y

After then setting them equal to one other:

```
        y = yTemp;
        x = xTemp;
        return 2*n;
```

and exiting the function, y and x seem to lose the extra length.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: You pass the pointers by value. If you want to change them in the function and have the caller get the new value, you have to pass them by reference. Also, make sure to `free[]` the old values. (But why not use vectors and avoid all this complex, fragile nonsense?)

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit new to this, would it just be free(xTemp); free(yTemp); ?

Comment: probably this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518809/c-programming-functions-with-arrays/27519173#27519173) will help you

Comment: @aeongrail Sorry, I meant `delete[]`. If you `new[]` something, you must `delete[]` it. Do not use just `delete`, that's for the non-array version, `new`, not the array version, `new[]`.

Comment: I'm Deleting my array's like this: is that correct? for (i = 0; i <=n; i++) {
    delete[] yTemp[i];
   }
   delete[] yTemp;
   delete[] xTemp;

Comment: @aeongrail That's correct for when you're done with them. If you expect `yTemp`, however, you probably don't want to delete the inner elements because they'll be part of the expanded array (perhaps, it depends on your exact implementation). But please, just use something like `std::vector`.

Comment: Using ProgramAlarm's answer, things seem to work, but the deletion of those vectors still seems to not make the code work. Will the temp variables not be removed once I exit the function anyway?

Comment: @aeongrail You do not delete variables in C++ (or any language I'm aware of); you delete objects. You want the function to delete the old, smaller arrays that you're no longer going to be using.

Answer (score 5):

Your assignments to `y` and `x` before the `return` are setting the local values of those variables, not the ones passed in from the caller.  To do that, you can change your function declaration to

```
int resize(double *&x, double **&y, int n){
```

which will allow changing the caller's values.