# Passing two dimensional array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Try not to get lost in the broadness, as stated in a comment; it's a simple problem of passing an array to a function. I don't know anything about that. I thought I had to use pointers which I didn't understand how to do with two dimensions in the function definition but I scrapped that because I read I could use array indexing. I must have messed up somewhere.

My program is supposed to be a logo-like simulation where you have a turtle drawing shapes. The "programs" are stored in arrays which I made two dimensional for the 5 move forward command. Everything is outputted to a 50 x 50 two dimensional array. Output array is filled with zero characters. Shapes are drawn with asterisks. Each case for the switch is a command.

- 1 Pen up
- 2 pen down
- 3 turn right
- 4 turn left
- 5 move forward; second dimension holds amount to move forward
- 6 print array
- 9 sentinel (close program).

I get the following output when I run the code.

> 0000Error: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default Case                Error: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default CaseErro                r: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default CaseError: Default Case

After some test data I find that none of the values I put in the array are there when I try to access them later with the function. Something is wrong with the passing of the array to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_program(int arr[2][9]);

int main(void){

    int program_array[2][9] = {{0}};

    program_array[0][0] = 2;//Putting program into array line by line

    program_array[0][1] = 5;
    program_array[1][1] = 12;

    program_array[0][2] = 3;

    program_array[0][3] = 5;
    program_array[1][3] = 12;

    program_array[0][4] = 3;

    program_array[0][5] = 5;
    program_array[1][5] = 12;

    program_array[0][6] = 1;

    program_array[0][7] = 6;

    program_array[0][8] = 9;

    read_program(program_array);
}

void read_program(int arr[2][9]){
    int pen_down = 0;
    int direction = 2;
    char floor[50][50] = {{'0'}};
    int pen_x = 0;
    int pen_y = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++){
        switch(arr[0][i]){ //Problem starts here
            case 1:{
                pen_down = 0;
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                pen_down = 1;
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                if(direction == 3)
                    direction = 0;
                else
                    direction++;
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                if(direction == 0)
                    direction = 3;
                else
                    direction--;
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                switch(direction){
                    case 0:{
                        if(pen_down == 1)
                            for(int k = 0;k < arr[1][k];k++){
                                floor[pen_x][pen_y - k] = '*';
                                pen_y += k;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:{
                        if(pen_down == 1)
                            for(int k = 0;k < arr[1][k];k++){
                                floor[pen_x + k][pen_y] = '*';
                                pen_y += k;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        if(pen_down == 1)
                            for(int k = 0;k < arr[1][k];k++){
                                floor[pen_x][pen_y + k] = '*';
                                pen_y += k;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:{
                        if(pen_down == 1)
                            for(int k = 0;k < arr[1][k];k++){
                                floor[pen_x - k][pen_y] = '*';
                                pen_y += k;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            case 6:{
                for(int k = 0;k < 50;k++){
                    for(int l = 0;l < 50;l++){
                        printf("%c", floor[k][l]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 9:{
                break;
            }
            default:{
                printf("Error: Default Case");
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is print out the value of `i` in the default case so you know when the problem occurs.  You should probably print out `arr[0][i]` too.  And you should include a newline at the end of the printing.  You should meditate (hard) on why your loop goes from `i = 0` to `i = 19` and what that means given that you define the array as `int arr[2][9]`.  Can you say "array index out of bounds"?

Comment: I get info like: `0000Error: Default Case (i = 9; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 10; arr[0][i] = 12)
Error: Default Case (i = 11; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 12; arr[0][i] = 12)
Error: Default Case (i = 13; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 14; arr[0][i] = 12)
Error: Default Case (i = 15; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 16; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 17; arr[0][i] = 0)
Error: Default Case (i = 18; arr[0][i] = 1786245174)
Error: Default Case (i = 19; arr[0][i] = 32767)`  Your switch doesn't handle 0 or 12, let alone the random numbers at the end.

Comment: All I see is "Here is a bunch of code full of magic numbers. It doesn't work how I want it to. Please fix help." Sorry. Way too broad for me to spend my time.

Comment: Fixed that. Thats all great but the problem is passing the array. None of the values I put in the array are there when I try to access them later with the function as @jonathan-leffler tests show.

Comment: your defined values starts from 1 to 12, and all values in range [10 .. 12] fall in default:, that is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `printf()` — another one:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++){
     printf("arr[0][%d] = %d (%d)\n", i, arr[0][i], arr[1][i]);
     switch(arr[0][i]) {
```

and it shows the values in the array as set in the main program.

```
arr[0][0] = 2 (0)
arr[0][1] = 5 (12)
0arr[0][2] = 3 (0)
arr[0][3] = 5 (12)
0arr[0][4] = 3 (0)
arr[0][5] = 5 (12)
0arr[0][6] = 1 (0)
arr[0][7] = 6 (0)
0arr[0][8] = 9 (0)
```

*Bug:* Those stray zeroes appear because you've not put a `break` between `case 5:` and `case 6:` for the main `switch` (there are breaks for the nested `switch`).

The data is passed to your code OK.  Also, with the loop bound set to 9, I got no 'Error: default case' messages — which is a major improvement.

The problem probably is in the drawing code:

```
 67             case 5:{
 68                 switch(direction){
 69                     case 0:{
 70                         if(pen_down == 1)
 71                             for(int k = 0;k < arr[1][k];k++){
 72                                 floor[pen_x][pen_y - k] = '*';
 73                                 pen_y += k;
 74                             }
 75                         break;
 76                     }
```

There is a gross over-use of `k`.

*Bug:* the loop condition should be testing against `arr[1][i]`.

I don't understand the intended logic behind the placing of the stars and the movements.  That's for you to debug.

*Bug:* Your initialization for `floor` sets one element to `'0'` and leaves the 2499 cells as `'\0'`.  If you view the output so that nulls are made visible, you get to see those — lots of those.

Add: `#include <string.h>` and `memset(floor, '0', sizeof(floor));`.

*Bug:* Your printing code in `case 6:` does not output a newline at the end of each line.

Note the basic debugging techniques used.  Print the data (either in the debugger or using `printf()`, making sure you end lines with a newline).  Eyeball what is going on.

Incidentally, I think you should redesign your array so that it is 9x2 (instead of 2x9).  Then you can extend the program much more easily:

```
int program[][2] =
{
    { 2,  0 },
    { 5, 12 },
    { 3,  0 },
    { 5, 12 },
    { 3,  0 },
    { 5, 12 },
    { 1,  0 },
    { 6,  0 },
    { 9,  0 },
};
```

At the moment, you need:

```
 int program_array[2][9] = 
 {
     { 2,  5, 3,  5, 3,  5, 1, 6, 9 },
     { 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0 } 
 };
```

This layout means that the program interpreter can only deal with one size of program; using the alternative, it could handle arbitrarily long programs.  You should be able to find a use for choice 7 as 'clear the array'.  You could revise choice 3 to accept a new direction in the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are passed between functions, by specifying all the dimension sizes except the top most dimension as one argument of the function and the second argument gives us the size of the top dimension of the array.

```
int largestElement(int array[][4],int row)
```

this has been answered in various questions. 
Look at this answer for complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518809/c-programming-functions-with-arrays/27519173#27519173)

Comment: It's permissible, but not necessary, to set the leading dimension as in the code in this question.  That is not a source of the trouble.